# Ionic 4 split pane - side menu cannot be swiped in

Tags: angular, gesture, ionic4

I've just initialized a new Ionic 4 project with the split pane template.

So I have an app with a side menu, which should be able to be swiped in. But it doesn't work.
In the documentation it's working:
https://beta.ionicframework.com/docs/api/split-pane

Here's the code:

```
<ion-app>
  <ion-split-pane when="md">
    <ion-menu>
      <ion-header>
        <ion-toolbar>
          <ion-title>Menu</ion-title>
        </ion-toolbar>
      </ion-header>
      <ion-content>
        <ion-list>
          <ion-menu-toggle auto-hide="false" *ngFor="let p of appPages">
            <ion-item [routerDirection]="'root'" [routerLink]="[p.url]">
              <ion-icon slot="start" [name]="p.icon"></ion-icon>
              <ion-label>
                {{p.title}}
              </ion-label>
            </ion-item>
          </ion-menu-toggle>
        </ion-list>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-menu>
    <ion-router-outlet main></ion-router-outlet>
  </ion-split-pane>
</ion-app>
```

Does someone know what I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

By inspect, there is a difference with associated style classes to  between Chrome and other browsers, with the same screen resolution:

- in Chrome: *menu-type-overlay menu-enabled hydrated split-pane-side menu-side-start menu-pane-visible*
- other browser: *menu-type-overlay menu-enabled menu-side-start hydrated show-menu*

So my work-around to show dinamically split-pane on left/right it's to add conditional classes according to resolution:

```
<ion-menu [side]="sideMenu"
        [ngClass]="{'split-pane-side': sideMenu == 'start', 'menu-pane-visible': sideMenu == 'start', 'show-menu': sideMenu == 'end'}">
```

In my app.component.ts:

```
@HostListener('window:resize', ['$event'])
    onResize(event: Event): void {
        this.sideMenu = this.platform.width() > 767 ? 'start' : 'end';
        this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
        this.changeDetectorRef.markForCheck();
    }
```

I hope it helps you!